# randdusing/ng-cordova-bluetoothle, parsing ble advertisement ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, bluetooth-lowenergy, ngcordova

using the randdusing bluetoothle plugin for ionic app, need to read the advertisement.

The ble scan returns with Start Scan Success :

```
{"address":"14::30:c6:60:e8;9f","name":null,"rssi":-50,"advertisement":"AgEGG/9SVgIADSw5YTNlMTQAAAJlAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA;=","status":"scanResult"}
```

**query:** need to decipher this json data and convert this advertisement data into array containing hex values of advertisement data? The advertisement data seems to be base64 encoded. Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

I made for this purpose a little helper function as shown below. The key is the `$cordovaBluetoothLE.encodedStringToBytes` as you can see in docs https://github.com/randdusing/ng-cordova-bluetoothle.

```
var encodedToByteString = function encodedToByteString(input) {
    var val = $cordovaBluetoothLE.encodedStringToBytes(input);
    var byteStr = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
        var byte = val[i].toString(16);
        if (byte.length == 1) byte = "0" + byte;
        byteStr += byte;
    }
    return byteStr;
};
```

The same goes for the opposite operation - that is sending data. You first need to get your hex-string into an array of bytes and then encode it via `$cordovaBluetoothLE.bytesToEncodedString(value)`.